# Display desktop using X11?

Tags: amazon-ec2, x11vnc

Client: MacOS latest.
Server: Ubuntu 18.04
EC2

I have somehow managed to test out that `X` forwarding is working.

It took a lot of time as I am new to MacOS, finally realised I need XQuartz.

I am unable to figure out how to display the desktop, or if it is even possible with `X`.

I tried:

```
ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 user@server -i key.pem
```

When I tried to connect using the `Screen Sharing` app, I got a connection refused error.

```
ssh -X 5901:localhost:5901 user@server -i key.pem
```

Same error as above.

I have done the settings changes:

Client:

```
Host *
    ForwardingAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
```

Server:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you attempting to send the full desktop over ssh to your mac server? Or do you just want to send individual X windows?

If you want to just use a remote desktop I recommend running a vncserver on the Ubuntu server and using a vncviewer client on the mac side of things. You can use SSH Tunnels to tunnel the vncviewer over ssh if need be.

Comment: @Natolio Thanks. I only want to use X windows. I have a particular app/program `ibgateway` which I want to look at. It requires some settings to be changed. In the time after posting the question I have managed to get `firefox` window to show up. But when I try the `ibgateway` I get errors such as `X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.` `java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.` I am going to check if java is installed next.

Comment: I believe that if you are attempting to send X11 over SSH, but the DISPLAY variable is set, that the DISPLAY variable will override sending over SSH. For example, there is a fun little application called `xeyes` that just pops up an little googley eye that I like to use for X11 testing. If I `ssh -X remotehost` and execute `xeyes` it will come back to the display that I SSHd from, however if I `ssh -X remotehost` and execute `xeyes -display someotherdisplay:0.0` then `xeyes will end up on the other specified display. I'm guessing that may be happening in your case behind the scenes.

Comment: Though in some of my own testing here, I may be wrong about that. I `ssh -X` to my remote server and then did `echo $DISPLAY` and it shows `localhost:10.0`. Then I `ssh` to the remote host without `-X`, while keeping the initial `ssh -X` session established. In the second `ssh` (no `-X`) session I `export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0` and then `xeyes` and it sends to my local display, presumably over the SSH tunnel. Maybe try a similar test to what I just did to verify that and we can go from there.

Comment: @Natolio, I am working on it. Java was not installed and the downloaded files as per some articles were supposed to be in `root`. I am now trying to put them in under the user and seeing if it works. Will update. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Natolio, it worked. I redid the entire process, keeping files in the user directory not root. Then navigated to the directory and `DISPLAY=:10 ./program_name`. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent, doing something like changing users (which sounds like it may have been happening at some point) can reset environment variables like DISPLAY and as such can mess up the X11 display forwarding. Glad you got it working.